# Namespace cannot be found after changing target framework from v4.0 to v3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 projects in a solution, 1 a dll, the other an exe. Both were using .net version 4.0 however no 4.0 specific libraries were used so it should be possible for me to safely change them to 3.5

I did this under both project properties, I built the dll fine. Now when i try to build the exe it cannot find the dll's namespace. I have readded the reference, but it still cant see it. When I reverted the .net version it did say I might have to modify the project files before it builds. I have tried to search for a solution via google but the key words I am using are too commonly used. Can anyone advise?

Many thanks, Chris

Edit:
Tried the following already..

- Reference DLL specifically whilst ensuring not 4.0 copy
- Delete bin and obj folders
- Restart VS

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Engine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I removed the reference to the "Engine" dll project in the exe project, I then readded it and it still cannot see the namespace anymore. I have restarted visual studio. I also tried referncing the dll manually, initially I accidentally selected the old copy which uses 4.0 and this told me I could not add a 4.0 library to a 3.5 solution, so I found the right file and the reference appeared fine but when I built it still could not see the namespace (code not changed). Therefore I just relinked it to the project in the same solution. Again it still does not see the namespace.

Comment: also when I initially changed the framework version the reference CSharp became unavailable, but according to the following link this is to be expected as the CSharp reference is specific to v4 of the framework and therefore not something I believe I need to be concerned about (and have removed) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en%20US/vssetup/thread/90cc76ab-f8b4-4d02-b758-29c54a36f422

Comment: I have also tried looking here but having a hard time finding a usefull post - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/threads

Comment: I deleted every single Obj and Bin directory and rebuilt - no luck

Comment: What's in your Output window after you rebuild the solution?

Comment: The DLL: Compiled with 0 errors. The EXE: The namespace Engine can not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than referencing the output DLL, have you tried setting it as a project reference instead.

Also, have you done a clean build of the solution incase any .Net 4.0 files were lingering? You can manually clean the project by deleting the bin and obj folders.

Have you tried removing the projects from the solution, creating a new .net 3.5 project and compiling that. Then add in the ddl project (Add -> existing project) and compile, then add in exe project without reference, compile then add in the references.

Odd question, but have you check the name spaces still. Can you call in your project the namesapce, i.e. `using mydllproject.model.myengine`

Comment: For a 3rd time.. I have tried this, and it does not work. Please see my comments above. I tried referencing the dll specifically. I have deleted ALL bin and obj folders and tried to rebuild. Thanks for your advice anyway pal.

Comment: @Chris, I have since made edits. Did you try creating a new solution with a blank 3.5 project, then add in the older projects? Maybe the solution file is the problem. i did read the other comments, but they didn't state to use project references, just reference the dll output directly.

Comment: @JonWillis: Thanks for the edits, I will try your suggestions now, I see the process of porting to code to a fresh solution as a last resort but it seems i might have to do this anyway. il get back to you. But "using Engine;" does not see the namespace (which has not changed)

Comment: @Chris, Porting shoudln't be too bad as you can just use add existing project, if it was pulling in each file then I would see it as a last resort indeed. Sadly one I had to do once when going from 3.5 to 2.0 for a SmartPhone project, but it was a tiny project at the time so time working out a fix was not worth while. +1 for a question that is actually a challenge to solve.

Comment: Hmm I tried setting up a new solution and porting the projects but same error, therefore the problem is definitely with the projects. I give up and curse microsoft, cry for stack overflow knowledge, and begin the task of manually rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Curse MS indeed, Word 2010 has corrupted my document here so a change in text size or line spacing, causes print view to explode. I to am now manually rebuilding my word document.

Answer (score 1):

I would open your project files as XML. To do this, close the soltion and reopen the projects only by clicking the down arrow on the File/Open button and selecting Open With... XML (Text) Editor. Check to make sure each project has a ToolsVersion="4.0" in the header. Check the RootNamespace and TargetFrameworksVersion elements to see if they have the values that you expect. At the bottom of the file, check the ProjectReference element within the ItemGroup. Make sure the GUID in the project reference matches the GUID that is defined in your solution file.

Finally, make sure you clean your project before you rebuild it. If you're using source control, check out the project into a new, empty sandbox.

Good Luck!

Comment: Each project has ToolsVersion="4.0" - OK, root namespace and target framework versions - OK, I have compared the GUID's from each project, with the other project and also the solution file, but these match - OK .. .T_T

Comment: Sorry that this didn't work out. If you're going to completely rebuild the solution, may I suggest that you run a diff on the old and new project files when you're done and publish the results? It sounds like you've uncovered a bug in VS 2010 and this information would be valuable to others who get hit with this.

Answer (score 0):

-Put dll and exe in 3.5
-Compile the dll only
-Delete the reference to the dll and readd it
-Rebuild the solution

Comment: Did you try to restart Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DLLs that you are referencing what kind of target runtime they require, especially the "Engine.dll". You could do this with the .NET Refractor for example. If they are compiled for v4.0, then yuou need to get versions for an earlier version of .NET runtime.

Comment: Again I have already tried this, this did not work "I also tried referncing the dll manually, initially I accidentally selected the old copy which uses 4.0 and this told me I could not add a 4.0 library to a 3.5 so I found the right file and the reference appeared fine but when I built it still could not see the namespace (code not changed). Therefore I just relinked it to the project in the same solution. Again it still does not see the namespace"

Comment: @Chris - Have you looked though your project files using a text editor? At times you see things in the raw project files that gives a hint...

Comment: I have actually, the framework versions are all 3.5 - there isnt anything sticking out at me so I feel I have already done all the basic checks :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to this. In my case it I had two projects, a 'class library' and a windows forms application in the same solution.

After changing the target framework of both the projects to .NET4.0 framework, and adding a reference to the class library in my windows forms application, it wouldn't detect the namespace of my class library.

Here is what I did that finally solved the problem:

1. Created a new project with .NET 4.0 framework as the target framework. I imported all my forms and classes into this project from the original solution.
2. Added the existing class library as a new project.
3. Added a reference to the class library project from my windows forms project
4. **For each of the class files under the class library project, I set the 'Build Action' to 'Compile'**
5. Right-clicked the class library project and selected to 'Rebuild'.
6. Then when I go into my windows forms projects, I can see the namespace when I use the 
   '**using namespace_name**' statement.

Note: Maybe you do not need to create a new project like I did in the first few steps. But changing the Build Action definitely did the trick.

Hope it helps.